# Angular Material: error "No provider for MatChip"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want use mat-chips into my component

**my-comp.module.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" #chipList>
      <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let role of user.roles" [selectable]="selectable"
        [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove(role)">{{ role.name }}</mat-chip>
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        <input
          placeholder="New fruit..."
          #fruitInput
          [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
          [matAutocomplete]="auto"
          [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
          [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
          [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
          (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**my-comp.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComp],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule
  ],
  exports: [MyComp]
})
export class MyCompModule { }
```

but it raise an error:

```
error-handler.service.ts:11 Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatChipRemove -> MatChip]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatChipRemove -> MatChip]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatChip!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:717)
    at resolveToken (core.js:954)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:795)
    at resolveToken (core.js:954)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:795)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:17656)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:18345)
    at resolveDep (core.js:18716)
```

it seem all loaded into the module...

Comment: have you add `import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';` in your AppModule

Comment: if using the CLI, can you try killing the server and reloading it? Sometimes module changes confuse it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using code from the same file? It seems that the error you pasted from the console is from `error-handler.service.ts`, while you've only shown the code for `my-comp.module.ts` and `my-comp.module.html`. Could you check again?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into this same issue recently, and found the errors written to console to be unhelpful. If your issue is the same as mine, the problem is in your HTML. Change your HTML to this.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" #chipList>
      <mat-chip-list>
         <mat-chip *ngFor="let role of user.roles" [selectable]="selectable"
         [removable]="removable"
         (removed)="remove(role)">
            {{ role.name }}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
         </mat-chip>
        <input
          placeholder="New fruit..."
          #fruitInput
          [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
          [matAutocomplete]="auto"
          [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
          [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
          [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
          (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
      </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

The issue was that a mat-icon element with the attribute matChipRemove must be placed inside of the mat-chip element you are pairing it with.